What am I not understanding about sorting this list
I'm trying to sort my list but it's not sorting as expected. Why is this?
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
    $rscontent = Get-Item C:\temp\file1.txt | Sort-Object  LastWriteTime -Descending  
    "File1.txt last updated: $($rscontent.LastWriteTime) on server $(hostname)"
} 


The sorting has to be performed after you have all the data, not before:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers { Get-Item C:\temp\file1.txt } |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    ForEach-Object { "File1.txt last updated: $($_.LastWriteTime) on server $($_.PSComputerName)" }

Notable mention, Invoke-Command automatically wraps all output in psobject instances and attaches a .PSComputerName property to it, so as shown above, there is no need to invoke hostname in your scriptblock. See about Remote Output for details.
